# JOptionPane with Eclipse in Java not working

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, joptionpane

I'm using `JOptionPane` with `Eclipse` in `Java` not working.

This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class GarzaELE24 {


     public static void main(String[] args) { 
     int x; // team score
     int y; // score

     y = 13;

     //create scanner object
     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

     //prompt receive inputs from keyboard
     System.out.printf("%s%n", "Please enter your team's "
                        + "final score for the super"
                        + "bowl game:  ");     
     x = input.nextInt();

    String input = JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Congratulations 2019 Super Bowl Champions!");     
    if(x >= y){


     }
     else {

       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Better luck next time!");}

     }
}
```

Comment: Please explain ["not working"](https://web.archive.org/web/20180124130721/http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/).

Answer (score 1):

`showMessageDialog` is a `void` method. It does not return anything. In order to get user's input, use `showInputDialog`:

```
String input2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Congratulations 2019 Super Bowl Champions!");
```

I changed the name of the variable from `input` to `input2` since it is already declared before.

Comment: @EricaGarza As I see you are a new user. Take a look and read [what should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost right but there is a problem in this statement:
`String input = JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Congratulations 2019 Super Bowl Champions!");`

You have used .showMessageDialog which does not return any value. If you want to show a message dialog box then you should never assign .showMessageDialog to any variable.

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake in the following line:
String input = JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Congratulations 2019 Super Bowl Champions!"); because it does not return any value and cannot display which you actually want. Therefore, you should use this only:
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Congratulations 2019 Super Bowl Champions!");

Here your code:

import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class GarzaELE24 {

```
 public static void main(String[] args) { 
 int x; // team score
 int y; // score

 y = 13;

 //create scanner object
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

 //prompt receive inputs from keyboard
 System.out.printf("%s%n", "Please enter your team's "
                    + "final score for the super"
                    + "bowl game:  ");     
 x = input.nextInt();

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Congratulations 2019 Super Bowl Champions!");     
if(x >= y){


 }
 else {

   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Better luck next time!");}

 }
```

}